# How to find Uri when I have string path of .3gp file?

Tags: android

I have path (String path) to my file .3gp on phone and I want to get Uri from that path so I can play in VideoView. I have tried like

```
    video= Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

but it doesn't work. can someone show me how to find Uri when I have string path ?

Comment: `doesn't work` isn't a good description for a problem. Show us the context and the code where you try to use the uri.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
   videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Or,

```
   videoView.setVideoPath(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
// Set video link (mp4 format )
Uri video = Uri.parse("/sdcard/sticky.mp4");
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```